# Completeness of the space of measures under $d$-bar metric

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics

Does anybody know the reference to a proof of the following fact (which is not hard to prove, but seems to be well-known, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85984/density-of-strictly-ergodic-measures-in-the-d-bar-topology)): **The space of shift-invariant measures under Ornstein's d-bar metric is complete**.

Comment: I just checked: it's not in Rudolph's book.

Comment: It seems that you cannot find it in Shields nor in Glasner.